# How to obtain the content from Multi-Level JSON format in JAVA?

Tags: java

For example, a kind of JSON as below:

```
    { "x":"1","y":"2","z":{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}}
```

Put this as string in JSONObject argument:

```
    JSONObject jaob=new JSONObject(xxx)
```

and from method "get("x")" of JSONObject I can obtain the value "1"

```
     jaob.get("x")
```

But how to get "a" of the second level JSON format "z"???

When I try to obtain by

```
     JSONObject(jaob.get("z").toString()).get("a")
```

but it doesn't work.
Does any one have the idea?
Any response is appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is the type of the return value from the `get` method? When you understand that, the answer should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Have you looked at the api documentation for JSONObject?

Comment: Please take the time to read the [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) before posting a question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jaob.getJSONObject("Z").getString("a")
```

alternatively, you could use getLong or getString on `a`.

If you read [the javadocs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) it's pretty easy stuff. The reason yours didn't work is that `get` returns a `java.lang.Object` not a `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`.

Comment: Depending on the data inside of Z, you could also use .getInt("a")

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
JSONObject jaob = new JSONObject(xxx);

jaob.getJSONArray("z");

//or 

jaob.getJSONObject("z");
```

they both return JSONObject according to [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)